# POCO libraries in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder, unresolved-external, poco-libraries

I compiled the POCO libraries in VC++, then I used Builder's implib to make libraries for Builder. I added these library files in my application's debug directory, however, linker still throws errors like

```
Unresolved external 'poco::session::...'
```

Could you please tell me what is the proper way to import the POCO library in my C++ Builder application?

Comment: Did you ever get Poco going with your approach?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to build the POCO libraries in C++ Builder directly.  The POCO distribution doesn't come with a .cbproj file, but I found that it wasn't too difficult to figure out which files are required and then create my own Poco_Foundation.cbproj in C++ Builder.

If I recall correctly, there are some portions of Poco (involving template specialization) that C++ Builder won't compile.  I was able to work around a lot of the compile errors, but I had to just exclude some of the units because they had too many dependencies on the units that don't compile.  Most of the problems I found were in the Poco_Net library; I think the Poco_Foundation library compiled pretty easily.

Good luck.